# Different responses per defferent touch events

Tags: android

I finally figured out how to enable multitouch, after about a week of trial and error. I've encountered another problem, however. First of all, let me give an explanation of my app.

This is a pretty basic app. When you touch AREA_A on the screen, it will play SOUND_A. When you touch AREA_B on the screen, it will play SOUND_B. Pretty simple. I wanted this to work with multitouch, so I used an OnTouch event. I am now able to touch AREA_A and AREA_B on the screen at the same time, and get a sound out of both areas (proof that multitouch is working), but here's the problem. If I start touching AREA_A, and hold my finger there, then touch AREA_B (With my first finger still touching AREA_A), instead of hearing SOUND_B, I hear SOUND_A being played. I am baffled at why this is happening. I think things will be more clear if I paste the code, so here it is. 
(I went ahead and added my entire class, just so you could examine it from start to finish).

```
package com.tst.tanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager; 
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;


public class sp extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int bdsound, sdsound;
float x, y;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.view1);

    v.setOnTouchListener(this);

    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    bdsound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kickdrum1, 1);
    sdsound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd, 1);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();


    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(236,234,135));
    switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if (x > 1 & x < 200 & y > 1 & y < 200) {
            soundPool.play(bdsound, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
        }
        if (x > 1 & x < 200 & y > 200 & y < 400) {
            soundPool.play(sdsound, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:

        if
        (x > 1 & x < 200 & y > 1 & y < 200) {
            soundPool.play(bdsound, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
        }
        if (x > 1 & x < 200 & y > 200 & y < 400) {
            soundPool.play(sdsound, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
        }

        break;


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    soundPool.release();
    finish();
}
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getX()` and `getY()` functions always return the position of the first pointer. I suspect that this is causing your problem.

When you touch your second finger to the screen in Area B, the MotionEvent is of type `ACTION_DOWN`, so a sound will be played (just as you intended).  However, since you touched Area A first, and are still touching it, that position is the one returned by `getX()` and `getY()`.

To get the positions of specific pointers try using the `getX(int)` and `getY(int)` functions.  For instance, if you touch the screen with two fingers and want the position of the second finger, you would use

```
x2 = getX(1);
y2 = getY(1);
```

`getX()` is the same as `getX(0)` and
`getY()` is the same as `getY(0)`

You can check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX%28int%29) for more information.